# While working with Azure Speech SDK on Windows , how to get Device name for creating AudioConfig class

Tags: python, azure, speech-recognition, speech

I am creating a Windows client to translate speech using Azure Speech SDK. As part of this we need to create an object of AuidioConfig. However I don't want to use default microphone. I want voice from another microphone which I want to specify. However it receives an input called `device_name`. As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-select-audio-input-devices#audio-device-ids-on-windows-for-desktop-applications) we need to specify the device ID. However I am not sure how to get the Device ID of a specific microphone.

In the documentation Microsoft has given code to get Device ID using C++ or C#. However I don't know how to get the same using Python.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot and an easy way to find Device ID in Windows. I would like to share my learning.

While reading Microsoft Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-select-audio-input-devices#audio-device-ids-on-windows-for-desktop-applications), I understood the format of the device ID will be as {0.0.1.00000000}.{5f23ab69-6181-4f4a-81a4-45414013aac8}

I went through all the properties of the device driver in Device Manager, I found the property called **Device Instance Path**. Value will be something like **SWD\MMDEVAPI{0.0.1.00000000}.{8c85a4e8-3a66-4857-8883-96d100179b47}**. If you leave the initial part, the value represents the Device ID.

`{0.0.1.00000000}.{8c85a4e8-3a66-4857-8883-96d100179b47}`

Comment: In my PC, Device Instance Path: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0221&SUBSYS_103C81C5&REV_1001\4&33934FEE&0&0001  like, but when I used last part as a device_name="4&33934FEE&0&0001" the error continue: raise ValueError('only one of filename, stream, and device_name can be given') . Still searching solution for my situation

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using python, you can use [pycaw](https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw), which lets you use the windows CoreAudio API.

Here's an example of how to list all the input devices and their IDs, adapted from [this github issue](https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw/issues/50):

```py
import comtypes
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IMMDeviceEnumerator, EDataFlow, DEVICE_STATE
from pycaw.constants import CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator

devices = []

deviceEnumerator = comtypes.CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator,
    IMMDeviceEnumerator,
    comtypes.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER)
if deviceEnumerator is None:
    devices = []
    raise ValueError("Couldn't find any devices.")

collection = deviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlow.eCapture.value, DEVICE_STATE.ACTIVE.value)
if collection is None:
    devices = []
    raise ValueError("Couldn't find any devices.")

count = collection.GetCount()
for i in range(count):
    dev = collection.Item(i)
    if dev is not None:
        if not ": None" in str(AudioUtilities.CreateDevice(dev)):
            devices.append(AudioUtilities.CreateDevice(dev))

for device in devices:
    print("Found input device.")
    print(device.FriendlyName)
    print(device.id)
    print("\n")
```